# Bulk data file output PL/SQL

Tags: performance, plsql, oracle11g

In my PL/SQL function, I m going to output a csv file for 14M million rows. There will be 3 fields in each row.

Im afraid the I/O process running time. I can create and output more than one csv file for this batch.  I don want to use line by line output.

What is the best and quick way to writing file. For example, fetching data then filling into a record. And then write the file.

Thanks.

Comment: I found this article on UTL_FILE performance http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=425.

Comment: This article explains my question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 10g onwards, it is possible to write a CLOB to a file with a single call, using the DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE procedure. In the following example, we will prepare a temporary CLOB with our data instead of writing it with UTL_FILE. When all source data has been added to the CLOB, we will write it to a flat-file in a single call.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2
  3     v_file    CLOB;
  4     v_buffer  VARCHAR2(32767);
  5     v_name    VARCHAR2(128) := 'clob2file_buffered.txt';
  6     v_lines   PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  7     v_eol     VARCHAR2(2);
  8     v_eollen  PLS_INTEGER;
  9     c_maxline CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 32767;
 10
 11  BEGIN
 12
 13     v_eol := CASE
 14                 WHEN DBMS_UTILITY.PORT_STRING LIKE 'IBMPC%'
 15                 THEN CHR(13)||CHR(10)
 16                 ELSE CHR(10)
 17              END;
 18     v_eollen := LENGTH(v_eol);
 19
 20     DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(v_file, TRUE);
 21
 22     FOR r IN (SELECT x || ',' || y || ',' || z AS csv
 23               FROM   source_data)
 24     LOOP
 25
 26        IF LENGTH(v_buffer) + v_eollen + LENGTH(r.csv) <= c_maxline THEN
 27           v_buffer := v_buffer || v_eol || r.csv;
 28        ELSE
 29           IF v_buffer IS NOT NULL THEN
 30              DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(
 31                 v_file, LENGTH(v_buffer) + v_eollen, v_buffer || v_eol
 32                 );
 33           END IF;
 34           v_buffer := r.csv;
 35        END IF;
 36
 37        v_lines := v_lines + 1;
 38
 39     END LOOP;
 40
 41     IF LENGTH(v_buffer) > 0 THEN
 42        DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(
 43           v_file, LENGTH(v_buffer) + v_eollen, v_buffer || v_eol
 44           );
 45     END IF;
 46
 47     DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE(v_file, 'DUMP_DIR', v_name);
 48     DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(v_file);
 49
 50     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('File='||v_name||'; Lines='||v_lines);
 51
 52  END;
 53  /
```

File=clob2file_buffered.txt; Lines=1000000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:28.65

The CLOB-specific code is highlighted above and is self-explanatory (perhaps with the exception of the end-of-line character assignment on lines 13-17 which is different for Windows. UTL_FILE manages the port-specific end-of-line conversions for us, but with CLOBs we must manage this ourselves).

Of particular interest is the DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR call on line 47, which is our only write operation to the destination flat-file. We can see overall that this technique is similar in performance to our buffered UTL_FILE mechanism (the CLOB method was slightly quicker). We therefore have an alternative method for writing data, but there will be additional costs associated with using CLOBs (for example, temporary tablespace and buffer cache). If the volume of data to be dumped is high, then this method might put too much stress on our temporary tablespace and cause problems for other users (large sort operations, hash joins, global temporary tables etc).

Care should therefore be taken when using this method.